# Surprisingly Countable or Uncountable Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, infinity

By Cantor, we know that there are different cardinalities of infinite sets. $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable and - rather surprisingly - $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, too. And even more surprisingly, $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

I sometimes show Cantor's arguments in high school (where I teach) and they and their consequences are - indeed and expectedly - very surprising to learn about.

What are some other infinite sets which are surprisingly countable or uncountable?

Comment: Show them that two segment of 3 and 8 cm have the same cardinality. It is amazing and they will not believe you at first. the show that an (open) segment has the same cardinality of a line... Even less "faith". Actually any segment has the same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any integer $n>0$

Comment: To be honest 42 years ago I was shocked to learn at uni that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. Think about it... any real is approximated as well as we want by a rational nonethless $\mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero: it's mind blowing!

Answer (score 3):

Cantor set, the set of points in $[0,1]$ whose decimal expansion has no prefixed number (for example, those nombers such that theres is no 5 in the decimal expansion).

All of them are, surprisingly (at least the first time one see them) uncountable. And the Cantor Diagonal Argument is key in proving this.

Answer (score 0):

The set of natural numbers is countable as you have noted, also the set of all orderd pair's of numbers are countable
(Intuitively this is because the size of this set is very close to the one of all rationals). Since a countable set A "generates" the countable set (A,A) (Thats not quite correct notation) we can use this argument to show that ((A,A),A)==(A,A,A) is alse countable, so any set of pairs or triples or millions of numbers is countable.